# Extract Index from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is like below

```
   ID       Name        Age
   101      Bart         10 
   234      Homer        39
```

I convert it to a dictionary using
code  -:

```
    dic1 = df6.to_dict(orient = 'index')
```

For Example -:

```
      {101:{'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, 234:{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}}
```

But I want except the first column every thing else should convert to a dictionary .

```
      ID    list
      101    {'name':'Bart', 'age':10} 
      234    {'name':'Homer', 'age':39}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and what's not working. Also, try to be more specific about what it is you're trying to achieve. The expected output you show is *also* not a valid python data structure. Are you just hoping to print the index and value as in [@Trock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007472/3888719)? See this guide on [how to ask a question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: Still `[101:{'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, 234:{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}]` is not valid in python.

Comment: @HenryEcker {101:{'name':'Bart', 'age':10}, 234:{'name':'Homer', 'age':39}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with the `.keys()` and `.values()` of a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [101, 234], "Name": ["Bart", "Homer"], "Age": [10, 39]})
records = df.set_index("ID").to_dict(orient="index")
pd.DataFrame([[v] for v in records.values()], index=records.keys())
```

which prints

```
                                0
101   {'Name': 'Bart', 'Age': 10}
234  {'Name': 'Homer', 'Age': 39}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your initial dataframe which I called `df`, I took the `Name` and `Age` columns and converted those to a dictionary using your `to_dict` example. I grabbed the values using python's `values()` method, and assigned that to a `lists` variable. I then created a new dataframe with the IDs of the first dataframe and the new column.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[101, "Bart", 10], [234, "Homer", 39]], columns = ["ID", "Name", "Age"])
lists = df[['Name', "Age"]].to_dict(orient = 'index').values()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID": df["ID"], "lists": lists})
```

[image]

If you want the `ID` column to be the primary key you can call

```py
df1.set_index("ID")
```

which yields this
[image]